# $k$ being given, probability that when selecting two numbers $a,b$ in $\{1,2,\cdots n\}$, one has $a<k<b$

Tags: statistics

Two numbers are choosen at random from the sequence of number 1,2,3,.........n. what is the probability that one of them is less than k and other is greater than k?

Comment: (a) Could you edit your own thoughts into the question. (b) Did you ask a similar question recently? (c) Are the numbers chosen with or without replacement (i.e. might they be equal to each other)?

Comment: No I didn't ask any questions yet. this is my first question

Comment: Without replacement and they can't be same as one is greater than k and other is less than k

Comment: What is the probability that the first draw is $<k$?  Given that, what is the probability that the second draw is $>k$?

Comment: That is what we have to find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $k=1$ and $k=n$, the probability is $0$.

Let us assume that $1<k<n$.

First of all, the total number of choices is $B=\binom{n}{2}=\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}$ and we are in an equiprobability context, each elementary event has probability

$$p=\dfrac{1}{B}=\dfrac{2}{n(n-1)}$$

Besides, there are $(k-1)(n-k)$ ways to "build" a favorable case.

Explanation : There are $k-1$ (resp $n-k$) ways to select a number to the left (resp. right) of $k$.

Therefore, the result is :

$$P_k=(k-1)(n-k)p=\dfrac{2(k-1)(n-k)}{n(n-1)}$$

Here is the graphical representation, in the case $n=20$, of the values of $P_k$.

Please note that $P_k$ is maximal and $\approx 1/2$ when $k$ is "halfway" (here : $k=10$ or $11$):

[image]